# Aid with UPDATE function

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a code which runs after somebody clicks on a "Delete Account" button and it should change "deleted" value from 0 to 1, but apparently my code isn't working. Can anybody help me finding the problem?

```php
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=user_db;charset=utf8';

        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username1, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET deleted = :1 WHERE username = :$username";
        $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute("1, $username");
        header("location:logout.php");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **[bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) - Binds a parameter to the specified variable name**

You need to use bind params

```
 $stmt= $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET deleted = '1' WHERE username = :username");
 $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 header("location:logout.php");
```